# media queries not working in chrome but works on iphone

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I added this at the bottom of my stylesheet

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

body {
 background: #000 !important;

 }

}
```

It works fine on iphone but I want to test in ff or chrome by resizing the browsers  and it does add the style. How can I get it working?

Comment: You can read more about media queries on http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `-device`

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {

body {
 background: #000 !important;

 }

}
```

`min-width max-width` measures the width of your browser window. `min-device-width max-device-width` measures the width of the device (ie. your monitor) which will never change

Comment: that works fine. thanks. But what does -device do? Do I risk break this on handheld devices by removing? edit: you just answered my question

Comment: As i mentioned, -device measures the dimensions of the device you are using (phone, monitor, laptop screen etc.) not the browser window. On a mobile device the browser window will almost certainly be the same width as the device width so both queries should capture the same device. Ie. it should work just fine without -device.